# Custom Product Type: Prevent cart aggregation

Tags: custom-product-type

I have set up a custom product type for my configurator in magento. Now everything seems to be fine. If I do a second conf with the existing product, not a second "row" is added to the cart. It does sum up the cart item to be an amount of 2.

How can I prevent this?

This is the code in config.xml:

```
<product>
            <type>
                <econfigurator translate="label" module="econfigurator">
                    <label>Econfigurator Product</label>
                    <model>econfigurator/product_type</model>
                    <price_model>econfigurator/product_price</price_model>
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    <composite>1</composite>
                    <can_use_qty_decimals>0</can_use_qty_decimals>
                </econfigurator>
            </type>
        </product>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is to override the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::representProduct` method.

add this at the top of it.

```
$itemProduct = $this->getProduct();
if ($itemProduct->getTypeId() == '`econfigurator ') {
    reutrn false;
}
// original code here
```